# Gmail search for unstarred emails in a label

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-search

Have tried multiple way and none of them has worked,

Used : `in:Test -is:starred` and `-is:starred in:TEST` and other option, None of them worked, `in:Test -is:starred` has listed all started email in Test label, but the inverse is no working, please help me in resolving this.

Comment: when you say it isn't working are you getting: no results, way too many results, an extra result or two, or an error?

Comment: getting all emails in the search results including starred and unstarred

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the star is associated with a message, not the entire conversation.  So when you use:

- `is:starred` it returns all conversations where at least one message in the conversation has a star.
- `-is:starred` returns all conversations where at least one message is unstarred.

Unfortunately  when you look at the list in the GUI all the Conversations in the first search have stars next to them. For the second search with `-is:starred` most will not have stars, but a few conversations will have stars because one or more of the messages has a star and at least one message doesn't have a star.

As a test you can turn off conversations under settings, and then you will get the consistent results you expect.

Comment: Thanks turn off conversations under settings worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

What you have tried *should* work. Although "officially" you should use the `label:` operator to search within a label, and labels are not case-sensitive. So, the following *should* also work:

```
label:test -is:starred
```

Note that if your label contains spaces then replace spaces with hyphens (`-`) in your search phrase.

However, if you've enabled multiple stars then you might need to change the operator (not tried). For example:

```
has:yellow-star
```

Reference:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en-GB

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering this , however i have tried above option with no luck , and i have referred the same link you have provided.

Comment: FWIW this does appear to work OK for me. So I'm wondering if there is "something different" in your case?

Comment: getting all emails in the search results including starred and unstarred

Comment: What if you try just `-is:starred` (without the `label:test`)?

Comment: it is working then , but when combined with labels it is not working

Comment: turn off conversations under settings worked for , but i will vote up your answer for your efforts. Thanks